# Azure iot and stream analytics issue

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

just wondering if i could get some help about azure iot hub and stream analytics.
I'm using this guide to build my simulated device https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/quickstart-send-telemetry-python
however, whenever i try to extend the json telemetry message to include more key pairs, stream analytics always gives me this error

```
Source '<unknown_location>' had 1 occurrences of kind 'InputDeserializerError.InvalidData' between processing times '2020-07-14T02:35:47.4125308Z' and '2020-07-14T02:35:47.4125308Z'. Could not deserialize the input event(s) from resource 'Partition: [2], Offset: [806016], SequenceNumber: [1698], DeviceId: [testdevicereal]' as Json. Some possible reasons: 1) Malformed events 2) Input source configured with incorrect serialization format
```

I've checked my json formatting and it seems fine, any clues?

Comment: take a look at what you're extending with and make sure it's valid json format.  As-is, you haven't shown what the extended info looks like.

Comment: Can you include the incoming telemetry message? Seeing as you're using Stream Analytics, you can go to the Query blade and check the Input preview window, switch it to raw and include the message in your question. A snippet of your code would also go a long way!